# How to do Tagging and excluding Filters in ElasticSearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, solr, lucene, bigdata

Like When filter is set for faceted/aggregated filter it should be excluded, so we won't get just one result.

If user selects some brand ,the result should come with only the selected brand ,but the aggregation should return all the brand filters that were already there, so that user can select  other brands also.

How can we do it in Elasticsearch? Same can be accessed in solr using Tagging and excluding Filters

Answer (score 0):

Use a post_filter to filter the search results but still show all data in the aggregation.

See [Post Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-post-filter.html):

> The post_filter is applied to the search hits at the very end of a
>   search request, after aggregations have already been calculated. It’s
>   purpose is best explained by example:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/shirts/_search -d '
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        { "term": { "brand": "gucci" }} 
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "colors": {
      "terms": { "field": "color" }, 
    },
    "color_red": {
      "filter": {
        "term": { "color": "red" } 
      },
      "aggs": {
        "models": {
          "terms": { "field": "model" } 
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": { 
    "term": { "color": "red" },
  }
}
'
```

Comment: How to check if user selects two colors? like  "color_red":  how will I create another? Using or operator .If yes please give the json

Comment: use the OR filter to add additional filters - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-or-filter.html

Comment: Ya.I got that .Thanks. :)